# Long click event is not detecting in phonegap-android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, phonegap-plugins

I have one issue with regarding to ***phonegap-android***.
Functionality is like when you touch on ***text*** **(on html page)** plugin will be called and dialog will be appeared. (Through which I have entered some text)
Now when I do long click on ***text*** pop up will be appear with options like

> "Select all"
>   "Select text"
>   etc...

Now the issue is Option window appeared behind dialog,
I want to hide dialog when long click done on ***text***.
**NOTE:** I have used

> onTouchStart
>   onTouchEnd

to detect click and long click.
But it works only for first time click.
After dialog has been appeared and some text has been added into **text** long click is not working.
Just for clarification **onTouch** or any other listener will not work as it is not an android widget.

Comment: What you want to do exect???

Comment: when lonk click fired i want to hide dialog.

Comment: can you post some sample code so i can help you...yet what you try

Comment: Suppose I have one text widget, 
<textarea id="txt" onclick="pluginFuntion()" onTouchStart="callFuntion1()" onTouchEnd="callFuntion2()"></textarea></br><br/><br/>

In pluginFuction() i have started dialog and entered some text into **text** widget, when I press long click on **text** to copy text, it show options but it is behind the dialog. I want to cancel dialog.

Comment: Are you using jquey??

Comment: $('id of dailog box').dialog('close'); try this one

Comment: yes i m using jqery....
dismissing dialog is not an issue....i can do it.
the point is when i have to dismiss the dialog ??
i want listener which will be called on long click...
the issue is dialog created in android thru java, so onLongClick will not work.
and listener for **text** is not working after calling the plugin

Comment: if possible give/Send me your whole html page..i will i will check properly..

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery Mobile's TapHold event for long Click.

Here is the link:

**[1]: http://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/**

Comment: Ok.find @bhavana.I will find another way.Soon i will tell you.